# How to convert for calculating JSON?

Tags: python, json, api

***Code with json dumps:***

```
def intro ():
RUB_BANK = connection.call('GET', '/buy-bitcoins-online/RUB/transfers-with-specific-bank/.json').json()
    amount2 = json.dumps(RUB_BANK['data']['ad_list'][0]['data']['temp_price'])
    print(amount2)
intro()
```

This code work. It gives me correct result:

```
"916000.00"
```

```
But if i try:
def intro ():
RUB_BANK = connection.call('GET', '/buy-bitcoins-online/RUB/transfers-with-specific-bank/.json').json()
    amount2 = json.dumps(RUB_BANK['data']['ad_list'][0]['data']['temp_price'])
    print(amount2 + 20000)
intro()
```

Give me traceback

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

I need to plus 20000 to 916000.00 How to do it?

Comment: It's because amount2 is a string, not a number, so you're doing `"916000.00" + 20000`. What you need to do is convert/cast that string into a number.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that amount2 is a string at that point.

You simply need to do this:

```
amount2 = RUB_BANK['data']['ad_list'][0]['data']['temp_price']
print(float(amount2) + 20)
```

Comment: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '"915000.00"'

Comment: Note the guidance in [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) about questions that have been "asked and answered many times before".

Comment: @Antony - I fixed it. Use float() instead of int()

Comment: could not convert string to float: '"911000.00"'

Comment: @Antony, using `json.dumps()` is what's adding the literal quotes to your string. Don't do that -- you want to add just `float(RUB_BANK['data']['ad_list'][0]['data']['temp_price'])`, not `float(json.dumps(RUB_BANK['data']['ad_list'][0]['data']['temp_price']))`

Comment: I tried it many time. And look at another questions.

Comment: @Antony, ...the reason the other questions' answers don't help you is because you'se using the extra `json.dumps()`, so your strings have quotation marks in them, which `int()` or `float()` can't handle. Just take out that function call -- you have no reason to have it -- and the problem goes away.

Comment: @Antony - Fixed it by stripping out the quotes.

Comment: @Colin, ...why would you advise removing the quotes after-the-fact, as opposed to using code that never adds quotes in the first place?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - Your solution I better. I quickly offered mine in crosstalk, but will adjust my answer.